# url_encode in Ruby

Tags: ruby, urlencode

I read [the documentation of `url_encode`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.9.3/ERB/Util%3Aurl_encode).

Is there a table that tells me exactly which character is encoded to what, using  `url_encode`?

Comment: It *should* encode all characters *except* those which are permitted in the [URL RFC#1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and later [URI RFC#3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) specifications. There are SO posts that delve into the details; although `url_encode` might have some oddities (e.g. often times `+` might be handled differently depending on context).

Comment: It doesn't encode every character, only ones that are restricted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ERB's [`url_encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode) can be tweaked:

```
def url_encode(s)
  s.to_s.dup.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").gsub(%r[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]/) {
    sprintf("%%%02X", $&.unpack("C")[0])
  }
end
```

to:

```
def url_encode(s, regex=%r[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]/)
  s.to_s.dup.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").gsub(regex) {
    sprintf("%%%02X", $&.unpack("C")[0])
  }
end

url_encode('pop', /./)
=> "%70%6F%70"
```

In addition, Ruby's CGI and URI modules have the ability to encode URLs, converting restricted characters to entities, so don't overlook their offerings.

For instance, escaping characters for URL parameters:

```
CGI.escape('http://www.example.com')
=> "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com"

CGI.escape('<body><p>foo</p></body>')
=> "%3Cbody%3E%3Cp%3Efoo%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E"
```

Ruby CGI's [`escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeElement) also uses a small regex to figure out which characters should be escaped in a URL. This is the method's definition from the documentation:

```
def CGI::escape(string)
  string.gsub(%r([^ a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/) do
    '%' + $1.unpack('H2' * $1.bytesize).join('%').upcase
  end.tr(' ', '+')
end
```

You also override that and change the regex, or expose it for your own use inside your redefinition of the method:

```
def CGI::escape(string, escape_regex=%r([^ a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/)
  string.gsub(escape_regex) do
    '%' + $1.unpack('H2' * $1.bytesize).join('%').upcase
  end.tr(' ', '+')
end
```

[`URI.encode_www_form_component`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) also does a similar encoding, the only differences in characters are `*` and :

```
URI.encode_www_form_component('<p>foo</p>')
=> "%3Cp%3Efoo%3C%2Fp%3E"
```

And, similarly to overriding `CGI::escape`, you can override the regex in `URI.encode_www_form_component`:

```
def self.encode_www_form_component(str, regex=%r[^*\-.0-9A-Z_a-z]/)
  str = str.to_s
  if HTML5ASCIIINCOMPAT.include?(str.encoding)
    str = str.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
  else
    str = str.dup
  end
  str.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
  str.gsub!(regex, TBLENCWWWCOMP_)
  str.force_encoding(Encoding::US_ASCII)
end
```